# How To Generate a Random Number With Prefix in Python

Tags: python, random, numbers

I need to generate all possible numbers in prefix:

```
import random
prefix = "05"
print prefix + #all Possible Numbers Here
```

Comment: all possible random numbers? makes no sense.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please edit your question to provide more details about what you want to do. It is not clear with these 3 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean how do you generate a random number and prefix it with a give string? Using your code as an example, you could do this:

```
import random

prefix = '05'    
print prefix + str(random.randrange(1, 100)
```

That will pick a random integer between 1 and 100, so you can adjust accordingly. For a random non-integer, replace that with `random.random()`.